# npm install socket.io stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, msbuild, node-gyp, gyp

I'm going crazy with the installation of socket.io. I tried various solutions around the net but every time I get an error.
I followed the instructions at this [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) about node-gyp.
I have windows7 professional 64 bit.

here is what I get from the shell

```
C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc>npm install socket.io

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install   C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

/
C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel  build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files  (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets(507,5): error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a
supported PlatformToolset value is selected. [C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-    gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gypbin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets(507,5): error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a
supported PlatformToolset value is selected. [C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\utente\Projects\webrtc\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild
.....
.....
.....
```

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: `npm cache clean` and try again.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get the same error

Comment: It seems that `node-gyp` tries to build the socket.io with Visual Studio 2012. Do you have this version installed?

Try to run `npm install` with the actual VS version, e.g. `npm install socket.io --msvs_version=2013`

Comment: @pmed i get no error but it semms to me that socket.io was not installed because when i run node server.js i get an error "TypeError: io.sockets.clients is not a function"

Comment: According to the log above, you got an error during `npm install`. Some node.js packages are native binary addons and should be built from C++ source code. 

Usually Visual Studio is used on Windows. Do you have Visual Studio installed on that computer where you run npm install?